# I can share image to my app via Gallery but unable to share via FileManager or any other application

Tags: android, android-intent, share, gallery

i know my question is similar of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215636/share-image-to-my-app-via-gallery-but-unable-to-share-via-filemanager) but i didnt find any ans there, so i thought i should have ask here.

app is running fine if i share image from gallery but dont work if i share image from file manager. let me try to explain in details.

**EDIT**

i have build an app. basically i want to share some images from gallery or file manager to my app. my app only runs when i choose images from gallery and click on share button then click on my application name. that way i can get images selected by me from gallery. however, i do same thing from file-manager app ( i.e solid explorer , ES file explorer ) i couldn't get any images in my app.

may be i would get any solution here.

here is my **Manifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

and **here is MainActivity.xml**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent mIntent = getIntent();
    String action = mIntent.getAction();
    String type = mIntent.getType();

    if(action.equals(Intent.ACTION_SEND) && type != null){
        if(type.startsWith("image/")){
            Uri mUri = mIntent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
            ImageModel imageModel = new ImageModel();
            imageModel.setName("Image 1");
            imageModel.setUri(mUri);

            data.add(imageModel);
        }
    }
    else if(action.equals(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE) && type != null){
        ArrayList<Uri> mUris = mIntent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
        for(int i=0;i<mUris.size();i++){
            ImageModel m = new ImageModel();
            m.setName("Image "+ i);
            m.setUri(mUris.get((i)));
            data.add(m);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"from outside",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: "but dont work if i share image from file manager" -- please edit your question and explain, **in detail**, what "dont work" means.

Comment: edited.  hope it helps you to solve problem. tell me if u need more explanation

Comment: "i couldn't get any images in my app" -- what does this mean? Usually, problems in this area come from [misusing `Uri` values](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html), but that is just a guess.

Comment: The problem is I have put if else conditions to check whether my app invoked from gallery or out side from gallery ( means from launcher)  and i think that else part is also means for file manager but Its not working when I share images from file manager. I think there is no uri problem.

Comment: I can add Uri`s from galery and from file manager ("My Files") using the code in your question. I use Samsung s6 version 5.1.1 and it works. On my side Action and Type are the same when sharing images from galery or from  "my files".  Maybe try to debug and check what is the intenet recivied from file manager on your device and what it's action and type.

Comment: So how did you solve this? Can you please share solution?

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not remember it now. :)

Comment: @atul did you get solution, I also have the same issue

Comment: @Venkatesh Not exactly sure but please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46578918/1911652)

Answer (score 0):

> To share single from Gallery or File Manager  use this

```
       <activity
            android:name=".activityname">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                 <data android:mimeType="image/*" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

@VishalPatel

You don not need to change anything, every thing seems right. just put your code in the `onNewIntent()` Method. You need to override method in your activity.

Here is the demonstration :

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    Intent mIntent = intent;
    String action = mIntent.getAction();
    String type = mIntent.getType();

    //Your Code Goes Here...

    if(action.equals(Intent.ACTION_SEND) && type != null){
        if(type.startsWith("image/")){
            Uri mUri = mIntent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
            ImageModel imageModel = new ImageModel();
            imageModel.setName("Image 1");
            imageModel.setUri(mUri);

            data.add(imageModel);
        }
    }
    else if(action.equals(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE) && type != null){
        ArrayList<Uri> mUris = mIntent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
        for(int i=0;i<mUris.size();i++){
            ImageModel m = new ImageModel();
            m.setName("Image "+ i);
            m.setUri(mUris.get((i)));
            data.add(m);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"from outside",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```